# Segmentation fault even when buffer is large enough?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to test a buffer overflows but the program seems to crash even when the buffer is large enough which I cant see why

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int bowfunc(char *string) {

    char buffer[1024];
    strcpy(buffer, string);
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    bowfunc(argv[1]);
    printf("Done.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

with `bowfun()` correctly adjust `rsp` by subtracting `0x410` in gdb disassembly. Build as `gcc -o exec1 -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -g exec1.c`  run as `./exec1 $(python3 -c "print('\xaa' * 600)")` cause a crash, actual crash seems to happen between (500 and 600 bytes). Which I cant see, why gdb return this error

```
0x000055555555519e in bowfunc (string=0x7fffffffdcd4 'ª' <repeats 100 times>...) at exec1.c:10
```

also the maximum command length and arguments size seems to be fine with `xargs --show-limits </dev/null` giving:

```
Your environment variables take up 4531 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2090573
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2086042
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
Maximum parallelism (--max-procs must be no greater): 2147483647
```

Comment: The string is being printed using UTF-8 encoding, so it's 1201 bytes.

Comment: @Barmar why this happens when I'm telling python to print data as hex valuse ```\xaa``` is one byte while ```a``` are UTF encoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Python command is printing 1201 bytes.

```
$ python3 -c "print('\xaa' * 600)" | wc -c
    1201
```

`'\xaa'` is printed as 2 bytes using UTF-8 encoding, and it ends with a newline. The newline is removed by `$(...)`, but `argv[1]` is still 1200 bytes.

Add

```
printf("%d\n", strlen(argv[1]));
```

to the program to confirm this.

Comment: well this is weird for me since python2 will print data as expected but python3 seems to cause this to change

Comment: @Khaled: This – the difference between `str` and `bytes` – is one of the largest changes from Python 2 to Python 3.  In Python 3, standard streams are opened in text (`str`) mode as opposed to binary (`bytes`), so you can only output data properly encoded for the users character set, which in our case happens to be UTF-8.  It just so happens that Unicode code point U+00aa, ª, in UTF-8 encodes to two bytes, 0xC2 0xAA.